# Javascript Game controle Clear timeOut

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, cleartimeout

I wanted to build a small game in my online keyboard program and was wondering if some of you more experienced javascript developers could help me wiht my onmouseover controles. I can't seem to make onmouseout stop the onmouseover function from repeting.

```
var GameControleUPLEFT;

var GameControleTime =  25;

document.getElementById('SpillKontrollOppVenstre').onmouseout=function cleartimeout(GameControleUPLEFT){};

document.getElementById('SpillKontrollOppVenstre').onmouseover=function(){LHPlAYCONTROLEUPLEFT();};
function LHPlAYCONTROLEUPLEFT(){ // Player holding up-left
elf.y -= elf.speed * modifier;
elf.x -= elf.speed * modifier;
document.getElementById("GameInfo").innerHTML = "up - left";
for (i=0;i<blocks.length ;i++ )
if (isTouching(elf,blocks[i]))
{
            elf.y = blocks[i].y + blocks[i].h +1
        }
}
GameControleUPLEFT=setTimeout(LHPlAYCONTROLEUPLEFT,GameControleTime);
GameControleUPLEFT;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uc6805yf/1/

Comment: First, thank you for taking time to answere me. Now the function doesn't repete. I need function to repete until onmouseout.

Comment: I repleced upleft controle button with your code. http://lifther.org/Test/Fang_frukten2_test.html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uc6805yf/2/

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: just making some movement controles. I can see your code works, but I can't seem to adapt it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uc6805yf/3/

Comment: I'm struggeling. The set and clear interval is on line 284 and the functionis on line 333 . lifther.org/Test/Fang_frukten2_test.html  It's the clear interval that doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never mind. Found the problem :)

Comment: Sorry, was away, what was the problem

Comment: The variables was still inside a function (modifier). It didn't show on the short code snippet you looked at for me. But thanks a million. It was really helpful. :)